# Way to cluster Similar user behavior from frequent item set

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I'd like to cluster similar users' behavior on a transaction data set. What's the easiest/best algorithm to do this?

Assume I have 1000 transactions of user purchases.  I need to cluster similar users based on items purchased.

this is an portion from my data set

```
    T1  U1  T1,T2,T3,T4
    T2  U2  T7,T5,T1
    T3  U3  T1,T3,T2,T9
    T4  U4  T9,T2,T5
    T5  U5  T2,T5
    T6  U6  T7,T8
    T7  U7  T1,T5,T4
    T8  U8  T5,T3,T1,T9
    T9  U9  T9,T2
    T10 U10 T1,T7,T6,T5

T = 1..n for transactions 
U = 1..m for users 
T = 1..l for items
```

Comment: You haven't adequately described your data, so it's hard to give you help.  Can you give some metrics of interest to you?  For instance, how many items are there, how many users, what is the general distribution of items purchased, and what does "similar" mean to your model?  I'll give you a general answer below -- but you *really* need to read the intro documentation before you post again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on your definition of "similar".  From what you've described, I think that you want to build a data frame with one row per user; each item is a column in that frame.  The data value indicates whether that user has purchased that item (True / False or 1 / 0).

Now you need to decide what "similar" means.  You can get some idea by running a few k-means tests to see what looks sensible, or perhaps random forest or naive Bayes to help with your similarity decisions.

Once you've done that research, write an affinity function that suits your feeling of "similar".  Build a graph that connects users, with the edge weights being the affinity between those two users.  Now you can use almost any non-spectral clustering method to get what you want; a decent hierarchical clustering will likely give you a good range of clusters from which to choose.

Comment: Thanks Mr.Prune is there any way to form that items by its real frequency.. because item has been purchased one or many times its give me a unique value 1 .

Comment: Of course; when you build the table, just add the frequencies instead of using logical "or".